# matlab nearest neighbor interpolation result

Tags: matlab, interpolation

```
vq = interp1(v, xq, 'nearest', 0)
```

I expected the nearest neighbor interpolation is like `round`(xq) and get the values in `v`. For example:

```
v = [1 0];
xq =  0.4 : 0.2 : 2
xq =
     0.4   0.6   0.8   1.0   1.2   1.4   1.6   1.8   2.0

round(xq)
ans =
     0     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2

vq = interp1(v, round(xq), '', 0) % get ones for round(xq) == 1
vq =
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

I expected 'nearest' does similar to above `round`. However,

```
vq = interp1(v, xq, 'nearest', 0)
vq =
     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

This is neither `round`(xq), nor `floor`, nor `ceil`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your first three points (0.4, 0.6, 0.8) are out of the domain (which is [1, 2]). So interp1 uses the ‘extrapval’, which you’ve set to zero.

Try:

```
vq = interp1(v, xq, ‘nearest’, ‘extrap’)
```

Although that will return 1 for all x < 1, not sure if that’s what you want.

Comment: `v = [1 0];`. Where did you get that 2 from?

Comment: The documentation. "When v is a vector, the default points are 1:length(v)." You are passing it a 2-element vector, so it assumes that `x = 1:2`. So, you're effectively passing: `vq = interp1(1:2, v, xq, 'nearest', 0)` and for any `x<1` or `x > 2`, it will return the `extrapval`, which you set to zero.

Comment: @bconrad That is the exact reason. It happens only to edge values. I tried to shift the x from 1:2 to (1:2)-0.5 and more, but none of them solves the edge problem. So now I stick with the round(xq) solution.